# Deploying django app with heroku -- gunicorn not installing

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a simple Django app. I have a requirements.txt file, with a number of dependencies declared. When I push to heroku, it says that it's installing the dependencies I declare:

```
Downloading/unpacking gunicorn==19.1.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u52128/gunicorn/setup.py) egg_info for package   gunicorn
```

However, when I run the command 'heroku ps:scale web=1' (as recommended in the heroku tutorial) I get the following output:

```
Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:1X.
```

When I check with 'heroku ps' I get the following output:

```
=== web (1X): gunicorn poem_maker.wsgi:application
web.1: crashed 2015/01/08 10:46:14 (~ 3m ago)
```

Looking at the logs, I see the following output:

```
2015-01-08T06:46:14.481013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command gunicorn poem_maker.wsgi:application
2015-01-08T06:46:15.214361+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
```

It seems to me that I'm doing this correctly -- the gunicorn command should be found!

Thanks,

Dean

Comment: What does your Procfile look like?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The only line in my Procfile is the following: web: gunicorn poem_maker.wsgi

Comment: Can you try `bin/gunicorn`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I replaced 'gunicorn' with 'bin/gunicorn' in my Procfile, and I got the following output: `bash: bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you share more pip install logs? At the end there is summary what was installed - was gunicorn there?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line in your Procfile when you run

`gunicorn poem_maker.wsgi:application`

try `web: gunicorn poem_maker.wsgi` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you have missing gunicorn, install it

```
pip install gunicorn
```